# How to create Jest mock function with Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to mock an axios module by create this Promise function

```
// __mocks__/axios.js
export default function axios() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({ data: {} });
  });
}
```

But when i try to call it inside my `*.test.js`, i got this error

```
<PortalUploadForm /> › Submit Data correctly

expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledTimes()

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function axios]

Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function axios]

      87 |     await wait(() => {
      88 |       // mockAxios.mockResponse({ data: { ...uploadPortalResult } });
    > 89 |       expect(mockAxios).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
         |                         ^
      90 |       expect(nameInput.value).toEqual(null);
      91 |     });
      92 |   });
```

So how can i make a mock promise function using jest.fn()?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe add Axios to the question, please. Searching Promise information and always landing on Axios.

Comment: a bit late, but i was having the same issue. You need to make sure that your _\_mocks\_\_ folder is next to the file you are mocking. Otherwise it'll will return undefined when you call that function.

Answer (score 74):

It looks like you are trying to mock the default export for `axios` to be a mock function that returns a resolved `Promise`.

In that case you can create your mock for `axios` like this:

__mocks__/axios.js

```
export default jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }));
```

...and you can use it in a test like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const func = () => axios();

test('func', async () => {
  const promise = func();
  expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // Success!
  await expect(promise).resolves.toEqual({ data: {} });  // Success!
})
```

Comment: How do you avoid importing the `axios` module in every test file with this setup?

Comment: @luukvhoudt You don't.

Comment: @lmat-ReinstateMonica maybe not with this solution, but isn't it possible to just do `const myMock = jest.fn(); jest.mock('axios', () => myMock);`. Not sure if this is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @luukvhoudt no - that's not how mocking works in jest/vitest.

Answer (score 7):

In my tests, I usually just mock axios like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

jest.mock("axios");
const mockAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
```

Then in your describe block:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  mockAxios.request.mockImplementationOnce(
    (): Promise<any> => Promise.resolve({ hello: "world" })
  );
});
```